# Stripe Charge after service complete

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am creating project using angular and larval. In my project i am integrating stripe for payment.My requirements are:

User fill their card details but not charged.User is charged after technician completes their service.I don't know how this flow will work.I already setup stripe in my project:

```
$charge =   Stripe\Charge::create ([
        "amount" => 10000,
        "currency" => "gbp",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "payment",
        "receipt_email"=>$email
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$charge =   Stripe\Charge::create ([
        "amount" => 10000,
        "currency" => "gbp",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "payment",
        "receipt_email"=>$email,
        **"capture" => false**
    ]);
```

Notice the capture => false option here. This is what you need.
You will have to store the charge id some which you will find in your $charge variable.
When you want to charge actually charge do this,

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($stripe_charge_id);
$charge->capture();
```

$stripe_charge_id will be the charge id that you stored earlier.

Also keep in mind that the uncaptured charge expires in 7 days.

you should check the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/capture